# Git: Merging stashed changes to head

Tags: git

I have the problem with applying stashed changes from git.

1. I had a clean working directory.
2. I modified several files in the working directory.
3. I stashed those changes.
4. I was back to the clean working directory from (1)
5. I created and modified several files.
6. I committed these changes.
7. I unstashed the changes from (2)

After (7) I ended up where I was before at (2), and I suppose that'S the expected behavior. But not for me, since I thought after (7) I would have the changes from (5) and the stash is applied onto that changes. But for example, files created in (5) are deleted.

I am pretty sure I use this feature wrongly. Can anyone give advice, how I can actually apply the stashed changes to my working directory so that the changes in (5) are not lost?

**UPDATE 1:** Due to my IDE I am in the situation that I can roll back to the state where I stashed and due to Git I have can revert to the state of the implementation I did while stuff was stashed. I just don't know how to merge those two.

Comment: How do you mean changes (5) are deleted? Are they not showing on the file tree? or when you run `git status` those files are marked as `deleted: .....`?

Comment: The only time that applying a stash would delete files from Git if the stashed changes itself are delete operations. For instance if you delete a file and run `git stash`, it will put the file back to the file tree, but when you apply, later on, it will delete that file because your stash actually had deleted a file.

Comment: @PraveenPremaratne After stashing the changes I created a new file (amongst other operations). I committed these changes. Than I unstashed and the file was gone.

Comment: May you try and replicate it? Then tell us the commands so we can replicate it.

Comment: `git stash pop` or `git stash apply` will only touch the stashed files. Sounds a bit strange that `stash` is going to delete files created after the `stash` command. As @evolutionxbox said, we need to reproduce your case

Comment: The behavior you are describing is surprising. I would have expected the same that you expected. Show us the commands you gave and the output of the commands.

Comment: I will try to replicate as soon as I get a chance tonight.

Comment: Now I experimented to reproduce it and all my changes are gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you have committed your changes before `unstashing` i.e `git stash pop`, these modified files should be un-staged on the top of the previous commit. You might get these files modified or there would be a merge conflict. Chances are while resolving the merge conflicts, you'd have kept the changes from the `unstashing` and discarded the changes from the commit.

In any case, `git reflog` would  tell you the history of what exactly happened.